# jQuery cannot find children indexes

Tags: jquery, class, indexing, children

I have one of ul tag which include another child ul tag.
I'm trying to access child tag but it's not working properly.

```js
// php
$parent_index = 1; // Parent Index, li of ul 
$child_index = 2; // Child Index, li of ul


$("ul li").eq($parent_index).addClass("red")
  .children("ul li").eq($child_index).addClass("red");
```

```css
.red {
  color: red
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul> 
  <li>Brazil
    <ul><li>1st</li><li>2nd</li><li>3rd</li></ul></li> 
  <li>Germany
    <ul><li>1st</li><li>2nd</li><li>3rd</li></ul></li> 
  <li>Italy
    <ul><li>1st</li><li>2nd</li><li>3rd</li></ul></li> 
  <li>Russia
    <ul><li>1st</li><li>2nd</li><li>3rd</li></ul></li> 
</ul>
```

If then the text of "3rd" had to change red color in Germany ul tag.

```
// php
$parent_index = 1; // Parent Index, Germany
$child_index = 2; // Child Index, 3rd
```

However it does not work at all. Am I wrong method in my jQuery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is your selectors, `ul li` will select all `li` in your page instead of just the parent one.

You can use a more specific selector, like add a class to the parent element then use that to select the elements

```js
// php
$parent_index = 1; // Parent Index, li of ul 
$child_index = 2; // Child Index, li of ul

// Jquery 
$(".parent > li").eq($parent_index).addClass("red").find("ul li").eq($child_index).addClass("red");
```

```css
.red {
  color: red
}

.red .red {
  background-color: blue
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
// html
<ul class="parent">
  <li>Brazil
    <ul>
      <li>1st</li>
      <li>2nd</li>
      <li>3rd</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>Germany
    <ul>
      <li>1st</li>
      <li>2nd</li>
      <li>3rd</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>Italy
    <ul>
      <li>1st</li>
      <li>2nd</li>
      <li>3rd</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>Russia
    <ul>
      <li>1st</li>
      <li>2nd</li>
      <li>3rd</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to access only first ul's and also only their direct children 
using `$("ul").eq(0).find("> li")`  and to prevent colorise al `ul>li` inside the parent `li` just add some extra color class to ul

```
ul {
  color:black;
}
```

Hope that what you're searching for :

See below snippet :

```js
// php
$parent_index = 1; // Parent Index, li of ul 
$child_index = 2; // Child Index, li of ul

// Jquery 
$("ul").eq(0).find("> li").eq($parent_index).not("ul").addClass("red").find("ul li").eq($child_index).addClass("red");
```

```css
.red {
  color: red
}

ul {
  color:black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>Brazil
    <ul>
      <li>1st</li>
      <li>2nd</li>
      <li>3rd</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>Germany
    <ul>
      <li>1st</li>
      <li>2nd</li>
      <li>3rd</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>Italy
    <ul>
      <li>1st</li>
      <li>2nd</li>
      <li>3rd</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>Russia
    <ul>
      <li>1st</li>
      <li>2nd</li>
      <li>3rd</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```